# CMD Script: How to close the CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting, cmd

I have created a small command that will let me launch Internet Explorer. However, I wish to close the small command prompt that shows up when I launch IE. How can I do this? This is my current code:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Internet
Explorer\iexplore.exe"
http://localhost/test.html
PAUSE
```

I am guessing if I take out the Pause. It will close the CMD box upon closing IE??

Also is there another command that I can use to simply create a command that will let me add something to the Menu with a small icon, which in turn runs the above. Is this complicated? Any tutorials I can use?

Thanks all

Comment: To what menu do you want to add the command? To the context menu of Explorer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `start` command:

```
start "title" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.example.com
```

Comment: Interestingly, this appears to launch the default browser, as it launches FireFox for me :)

Comment: why "title"?? use start "" "foo.exe"

Comment: It is for no reason, just to make the sample more explicit. I thought people might wonder more about an empty string as the first parameter. But it seems I've been wrong ;-)

Comment: @Russ: Did you omit the first parameter that is specifying the title? If you do start.exe will use the executable path as the title and then start the URL which gets opened by the default browser.

Answer (score 8):

you need this on the end

```
&& exit
```

For example

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://google.co.uk && exit
```

Comment: Strange I have placed EXIT at the end but it only closes after I close IE. I was hoping to close it when it spawns off the IE process, possible?

Comment: Just tried that same thing happens. I am on Vista by the way if that helps! I thought this was going to be a piece of cake but I haven't had my cake yet! I appreciate any more help.

Comment: If I put an exit at the top, it obviously closes the CMD!

Comment: No problem. I managed to get it working with the start title thing as suggested. +1 for continued help. Out of interest what OS are you running for the above to work. I am worried my current solution may not work on most Windows versions!

Comment: Windows XP. But this should work in the CMD shell in Vista and 7 and right back to 3.1, I believe.

Comment: I also couldn't get this working. On my XP machine the command window stays open until I close the browser. Maybe there is some misunderstanding in how the OP wants to call the script?

Comment: I see. Thanks, I will try it on a different machine as I thought that would work.

Comment: Aha - I don't think it's working because you've got it in a CMD/BAT file but I thought you were entering it into the CMD shell. Apologies, my mistake. This is not a bad resource to begin with - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx

Comment: Ah, I see now. This is for calling interactively.

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.example.com"
exit /b
```

But you really should not force IE, but use the default browser:

```
@echo off
start http://www.example.com
exit /b
```

exit /b does not work on win9x IIRC, so if you need to support every version of windows **and** close the terminal window if the user double clicks your batch file, go with:

```
@echo off
start http://www.example.com
cls
```

Comment: "But you really should not force IE, but use the default browser": Maybe the requirement is to **force** the use of IE for a certain URL? I guess the OP will know better ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also launch your program with the `/c` switch, which terminates the cmd once its finished executing

for example

```
cmd /c "%ProgramFiles%\InternetExplorer\iexplore.exe" http://localhost/test.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add 'start' in front of every program you launch, elsewhere your script is going to wait until it's finished.

Comment: This just spawned another CMD prompt!

Comment: well just put it in front of your IE, that is what I wanted to say with programm

Comment: another trick is to add "start explorer.exe " and the program, which is equivalent to launching the app within windows

Answer (score 0):

A little late here, but running it in minimized mode or invisible mode might be another option. Source: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/

Running .BAT or .CMD files in minimized mode
To run a batch file in a minimized window state, follow these steps:

1. Create a shortcut to the .BAT or .CMD file. To do so, right click on the file, click Send To, Desktop (create shortcut)
2. Right click on the shortcut and choose Properties
3. In the Run: drop down, choose Minimized
4. Click OK
5. Double-click the shortcut to run the batch file in a minimized window state.

Answer (score 0):

### "Mind the gap!"

**Command Prompt always takes the empty space as separator, unless it's enclosed in double quotes.
So, if any Path**, or **Program/File Name**, or **anything includes empty space/es**, **must closed in quotes.**

- *eg.* `"C:/Program` `files/..."` *path/directory or* `"Any` `Program/Command/File.exe/cmd/txt..."` *Program/Command/File Name includes space/es.*

Syntax:

```
> start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.
START ["title"] [/D path] (start swiches here...) [command/program] (com/prog-parameters here)
```

`start "" /d "Drive:/the/Program/Path/..." "Command/Program Name.extension" "File-Name.extension"`

So, **it's usual fault**:
If you don't set the 1st set of quotes `""` for title (even if there's nothing to enclose), then the `START` command takes whats inside the 1st quotes set (eg. path! or Program Name!) and sets it as title... and of course, it messing up.