# How to close the cmd window after the batch file run

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file, cmd

I want to close the command prompt after the bat file run. From the bat file it's calling two python scripts and I have tried basic exit and many solutions to close the cmd in the bat file but non of were not working.

```
c:\python27\python.exe C:\Python27\EconomyNext\DetailEconomyNews.py %*
c:\python27\python.exe C:\Python27\EconomyNext\DetailFinanceNews.py %*
exit
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not closing the window? Exit closes the window when the commands completed execution, are the commands done or ongoing when you expect it to close?

Comment: After the python scripts run it's holding the cmd. Is there any way to kill the process.

Comment: it seems like your python is not exiting hence the cmd window being held open. You can try `start "" c:\python27\python.exe C:\Python27\EconomyNext\DetailEconomyNews.py %*` and then next line `start "" c:\python27\python.exe C:\Python27\EconomyNext\DetailFinanceNews.py %*`  this should launch python in its own shell and the cmd window should close, also then have a look at which python shell does not exit correctly

Comment: Thanks @GerhardBarnard . yes python shell was not closing. is there any way to close the python shell or kill it which is currently run.

Comment: Well, the shell should exit if the code is written properly, you need to determine why the code is not exiting properly, have you debugged your python code?

Comment: Need more context, it seems like your script files are not releasing the cmd , 
can i know the content of script files ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this post:
[CMD Script: How to close the CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522725/cmd-script-how-to-close-the-cmd)

It has a few options depending on how you are calling the CMD like:

> exit /b

or

> start c:\python27\python.exe
>   C:\Python27\EconomyNext\DetailEconomyNews.py %* &&
>   c:\python27\python.exe C:\Python27\EconomyNext\DetailFinanceNews.py %*
>   && exit

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but another option which worked from https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/

Running .BAT or .CMD files in minimized mode
To run a batch file in a minimized window state, follow these steps:

1. Create a shortcut to the .BAT or .CMD file. To do so, right click on the file, click Send To, Desktop (create shortcut)
2. Right click on the shortcut and choose Properties
3. In the Run: drop down, choose Minimized
4. Click OK
5. Double-click the shortcut to run the batch file in a minimized window state.